# How to use adb over Mobile AP (Portable wifi hotspot)

Tags: wi-fi, adb, wifi-tethering, wifi-hotspot

First : I know about `abdWireless` app. But my problem is different.

I am using my Android mobile as Mobile AP (Portable WiFi hotspot) for using internet on my computer. I want to use adb in wireless mode but the problem is - when i enable Mobile AP on my android mobile WiFi gets turned off and i am unable to use abdWireless app.

I want to use both `wireless ADB` and `Portable WiFi hotspot` at the same time. Is there any way to do it ???

Answer (score 12):

#### On Android Device:

- Make sure USB Debugging is enabled in Developer Options.
- Set adb port prop:

  - If rooted: Open a terminal emulator (like termux) and run the following commands:

    ```
    su
    setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
    ```
  - If not rooted: Connect your device to PC using usb and run on PC terminal/cmd:

    ```
    adb tcpip 5555
    ```

    You can disconnect after this and continue on WiFi.

    > **Note:** This step needs to be performed only once, but the prop is reset on boot, so you need to repeat this step after a reboot.
- Get IP address:

  - If using mobile hotspot, the IP address of the device would be `192.168.43.1` by default.
  - If using an external WiFi, you can get the device's IP address by running in terminal emulator:

    ```
    ifconfig
    ```

    This will print a list, one of those would start with something like `wlan0`, with IP in the second line (mentioned as `inet addr`):

    ```
    wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr ...
              inet addr:192.168.43.1  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              ....
    ```

#### On PC:

- Make sure you're connected to the mobile hotspot or the same WiFi as the Android Device. (You might wanna ensure that you aren't simultaneously connected to another network, like ethernet.)
- In the terminal/cmd, run:

  ```
  adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555 # The IP address of android device
  adb devices
  ```

Comment: Actually, 192.168.43.1 is hardcoded into Android, so it remains universal across all devices which can start a hotspot, so `ifconfig` is not necessary.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the info, didn't know that! Still, `ifconfig` will help if, say, you want to connect over an external wifi, to which both PC and Smartphone are connected.

Comment: but, this connects via the router? This doesn't connect via the mobile's hotspot, right?

Comment: @juztcode The instructions should work in both scenarios as long as both devices are connected to the same wireless network, be it router or hotspot.

Comment: You might need to restart `adbd` on the android device after `setprop` by invoking `stop adbd`, `start adbd`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable adb over USB in settings of your Android device. With this, you can already use most of the apps from Market.
2. In terminal in Android device, type `setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555`

Most programs from Market do only second. For first, they need root (like ADB over Wifi Widget).

Answer (score 1):

On newer android versions (around 4.0 or so, do not know exactly), you can do this without the need for a 3rd part app.

First, enable WiFi tethering, and connect your computer to the hotspot.

Next, go to `Settings->Developer Options` and check `ADB over TCP/IP`.

Now, you have to get your device's local IP. All you have to do is open up terminal emulator, and enter the `netcfg` command.

Look for the line that has 'wifi' in it, and look to the far right - you should see an IP address. This is your device's local IP.

Now just go to your computer, and type:

`adb connect <devices local IP>`

into a terminal.

Comment: Since Android 6, netcfg has been replaced with ifconfig.  But otherwise the step still applies